# Managing exception in dart

Tags: flutter, exception, dart

I'm trying to fetch an image from the internet, and display a profile photo. If there is an error while displaying the pic (maybe it doesnt exist at that location), I want to display a stock icon.

My code:

```
class AvatarWidget extends StatelessWidget {
const AvatarWidget({
    Key key,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return ClipOval(
    child: CircleAvatar(
        child: ProfilePicWidget(),
        radius: 70,
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey,
    ),
    );
}
}

class ProfilePicWidget extends StatelessWidget {
const ProfilePicWidget({
    Key key,
}) : super(key: key);

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget profilePic;
    try {
    profilePic = Image(
        image: NetworkImage(profileLink),
    );
    } catch (e) {
    profilePic = Icon(FontAwesomeIcons.userCircle);
    }
    return profilePic;
}
}
```

However even with a try-catch block, I'm getting an exception, and my icon isnt displaying. Why is it so?

```
════════ Exception caught by image resource service ════════════════════════════════════════════════
The following NetworkImageLoadException was thrown resolving an image codec:
HTTP request failed, statusCode: 404, http://google.com/data/data/media/2020/05/01/images_1_4CDIfHK.thumbnail.jpeg

When the exception was thrown, this was the stack: 
#0      NetworkImage._loadAsync (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:97:9)
<asynchronous suspension>
#1      NetworkImage.load (package:flutter/src/painting/_network_image_io.dart:49:14)
#2      ImageProvider.resolveStreamForKey.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/painting/image_provider.dart:501:13)
#3      ImageCache.putIfAbsent (package:flutter/src/painting/image_cache.dart:359:22)
...
Image provider: NetworkImage("http://google.com/data/data/media/2020/05/01/images_1_4CDIfHK.thumbnail.jpeg", scale: 1.0)
Image key: NetworkImage("http://google.com/data/data/media/2020/05/01/images_1_4CDIfHK.thumbnail.jpeg", scale: 1.0)
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
```

Comment: If you go to the url you are providing to the NetworkImage widget, it wont open. Try using a url that works.

Comment: I didnt post an original url. Assume the url doesnt work, and an error happens.. I'm trying to catch the error, which is not working. My question is why isnt my error handling not working

Answer (score 1):

Note that there's a line that says "Exception caught by image resource service": the exception was already caught.

To detect the error, you will need to use [`ImageProvider.resolve`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageProvider/resolve.html) to obtain the `ImageStream` and then use [`ImageStream.addListener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageStream/addListener.html) to register an [`ImageStreamListener`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/ImageStreamListener-class.html).  The `ImageStreamListener` allows you to specify an `onError` callback that will be invoked if the image fails to load.

Answer (score 0):

it's because `NetworkImage` catch and show the error before your try catch, if you want to catch the get Image error, you should directely get the data of image with a get request not with the `NetworkImage`